# ACTIONSCRIPT 3.0 seamless keyboard event

Tags: actionscript-3

I am at a lost, which is not surprising for a beginner to encounter. Im attempting to execute a smooth and seamless keyboard direction command. Issue occurs when keys are held which creates a delay and fragmented like movement. code is below and please be gentle im new at this   =)

```
var dx:Number = 0;


paddle.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, motion);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);


function motion (event:Event):void{
paddle.x = dx
}

function keyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){ 
     dx -= 20;
  }

if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
    dx += 20;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically keep track of when the key is pressed on `KEY_DOWN` and reset it on `KEY_UP`. Then, in your `ENTER_FRAME`, you check if the key is pressed, and move your paddle.

Something like this:

```
var isLeftPressed:Boolean = false;
var isRightPressed:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this._onKeyDown );
stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, this._onKeyUp );
paddle.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this._onEnterFrame );

// called when a key is pressed
function _onKeyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
{
    if( e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT )
        isLeftPressed = true;
    if( e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT )
        isRightPressed = true;
}

// called when a key is released
function _onKeyUp( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
{
    if( e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT )
        isLeftPressed = false;
    if( e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT )
        isRightPressed = false;
}

// called every frame
function _onEnterFrame( e:Event ):void
{
    // get our direction based on what key is pressed, and move our paddle
    var dirX:int    = ( isLeftPressed ) ? -1 : ( isRightPressed ) ? 1 : 0;
    paddle.x        += 20 * dirX;
}
```

This can easily be generalised for any key (keep a `Vector.<Boolean>` using the `keyCode` as an index) - Check out the PushButtonEngine `KeyboardManager` for the general gist: https://github.com/PushButtonLabs/PushButtonEngine/blob/PBE2/src/com/pblabs/input/KeyboardManager.as

Comment: thank you divillysausages, im much obliged for your insight and providing an answer that exceeded my expectations

Answer (score 0):

You should move the object when you have a key pressed by the user until KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP event is dispatched to know when the user releases the key. Here is an example of what you are looking for:
[Moving Movieclips using Keys with Acstionscript 3](http://www.flash-game-design.com/flash-tutorials/moving-movieclips-using-keys-with-as3.html)

I wish that it helps you. Good luck!

Comment: thank you Federico Dorfman, im much obliged for your insight and providing an answer that exceeded my expectations